# URL Encode form data

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

My app has a form for users to enter a string of content and a pass-key, which is posted to the server and encrypted. The users are given the encrypted value back. The app allows them to send the encrypted value back to the server with the pass-key and the server will decrypt the data and send it back in the response.

I can successfully post the data for encrypting and get my response back. The issue I have though is that the encrypted data contains characters that need to be URL encoded when the users post the encrypted data back.

This is the Angular 4 service function that requests the encryption.

```
    encrypt(data: CryptoData): Promise<Result> {
        let urlParameters = new URLSearchParams();
        urlParameters.append('content', data.content);
        urlParameters.append('key', data.key);
        let body = urlParameters.toString();
    
        return this.http
        .post('/api/encrypt', body, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => 
        {
            return response.json();
        });
    }
```

This gets back the encrypted result. Using a `Content` and `Key` value of:

> content: Foo Bar
>
> key: Test Key
>
> result: AAAAABAAAACUdwXxU1tfClnbpOaKEqNVPuZSxL+cawqTxH+ZAFmDlBAAAAD6o/EFwKE9aDIU1WLOCDtBbY7ERTiKgsXr4pnsvkm+Et+qpJwLORrvPn9QzmJ1uFI=

The result up there is a Base64 string and it contains characters, such as `+`, that I need to URL encode when the user posts the data back.

What is the angular way to handle this? The backend server is ASP.Net Core and I'm open to changing how my implementation there is done to handle any changes on the Angular side. At the moment I'm posting the data with this function, which causes the `+` characters to be replaced with spaces.

```
export class EncryptService implements OnInit {
    private options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.options = new RequestOptions({
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
            })
    }

    decrypt(data: CryptoData) {
        let urlParameters = new URLSearchParams();
        urlParameters.append('content', data.content);
        urlParameters.append('key', data.key);
        let body = urlParameters.toString();
    
        return this.http
        .post('/api/decrypt', body, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => 
        {
            return response.json();
        });
    }
}
```

The interface being passed in looks like this:

```
export interface CryptoData {
    content: string;
    key: string;
}
```

My ASP.Net Core API end-point looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost("~/api/Decrypt")]
    public IActionResult Decrypt([FromForm] CryptoRequest request)
    {
        string content = request.Content;
        string key = request.Key;

        // .....
        return base.Ok();
    }
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but you could base64URL encode the result.  A quick google found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url)..

Comment: I could try that. Wondering if the asp.net core model binders will handle decoding that for me, or if i'll have to do it myself.

Comment: You can absolutely base64URL decode in .Net core.. I'll get you an example and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use base64URL instead on base64.

For Angular, use [base64URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url).
Run `npm install base64url`
In your service or component beneath your imports, add the following:

```
const base64url = require('base64url');
```

Use like this..

```
const b64URLresult = base64url(result);
```

There is an alternative way to add javascript packages using Typings and Definitely Typed..  Didn't work first try for me on this package so gave the above solution.

And in your controller. Use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.Base64UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders)

Comment: How do I add the base64URL to my angular project? I know I can install if via npm, but not sure how to wire up a non-angular package to be consumed by a component.

Comment: I got this to work, thanks for the tip. While using this with Angular all you have to do is import it like a normal TypeScript object. `import { base64Url } from 'base64url';`